# Ubuntu 18 Server with 2FA for SSH

Tags: ssh

I want to set up 2FA on SSH on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server. I don't want to use Google Authenticator but Open Source solution.

Are there any guides for just using something free and other than Google Authenticator?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Those guides should work with other 2FA applications (such as [FreeOTP](https://freeotp.github.io/)) as well.

Google Authenticator uses [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm), and most 2FA applications such as the open-source [FreeOTP](https://freeotp.github.io/) use the same standard and you can use them in place of Google Authenticator.

For completeness, here is a (modified) guide from [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-ubuntu-16-04) to set up FreeOTP. Note that SSH public key logins will not ask for a 2FA token, if you want to use public key authentication with 2FA, see [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-ubuntu-16-04)'s guide (and disable password-based authentication).

- Update Ubuntu's repositories and install `libpam-google-authenticator` (this works with other 2FA applications as well).

  ```bsh
  sudo apt update && sudo apt install libpam-google-authenticator
  ```
- Set up a TOTP key for your user:

  ```bsh
  google-authenticator
  ```

  Answer yes to the `Do you want authentication tokens to be time-based` and `Do you want me to update your "~/.google_authenticator" file` questions.
- Scan the (big) QR code (most GUI terminal emulators let you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to reset zoom) with [FreeOTP](https://freeotp.github.io/) or the 2FA application of your choice.
- Write down the backup codes somewhere and store them securely.
- Configure `openssh-server` to allow 2FA logins. You can remove `nullok` if you do not want to allow users without 2FA set up to log in.

  ```bsh
  [ -e /etc/pam.d/sshd ] || echo '@include common-auth' | sudo tee /etc/pam.d/sshd
  echo auth 'required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok' | sudo tee -a /etc/pam.d/sshd
  sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  ```
- Find the `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` line and change it to `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to close `nano`.
- Restart `sshd` to apply the changes.

  ```bsh
  sudo systemctl restart sshd
  ```
- Open another terminal (so you still have access if it didn't work) and try to log in.

Comment: OathAuth and freeOTP didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work / what error did you get?